# Loop through a list of S3 buckets and put-bucket-lifecycle-configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

Beginner with scripting here, so please take it easy on me.

I'm looking for a script to dynamically call the AWS API put-bucket-lifecycle-configuration and parse through a list of all 200+ buckets automatically so I don't need to manually change the bucket names in the command. Here's what I have so far:

List and parse all accounts in org

```
aws organizations list-accounts
```

List and parse all buckets

```
aws s3api list-buckets --query "Buckets[].Name"
```

Command to put-bucket-lifecycle-configuration

```
aws s3api put-bucket-lifecycle-configuration --bucket BUCKETNAME --lifecycle-configuration file://lifecycle.json
```

Lifecycle.json

```
{
"Rules": [
    {
        "Expiration": {
            "Days": 3650
        },
        "ID": "ExampleRule",
        "Filter": {
            "Prefix": ""
        },
        "Status": "Enabled",
        "Transitions": [
            {
                "Days": 30,
                "StorageClass": "STANDARD_IA"
            },
            {
                "Days": 90,
                "StorageClass": "GLACIER"
            },
            {
                "Days": 180,
                "StorageClass": "DEEP_ARCHIVE"
            }
        ],
        "NoncurrentVersionTransitions": [
            {
                "NoncurrentDays": 30,
                "StorageClass": "STANDARD_IA"
            },
            {
                "NoncurrentDays": 90,
                "StorageClass": "GLACIER"
            },
            {
                "NoncurrentDays": 180,
                "StorageClass": "DEEP_ARCHIVE"
            }
        ],
        "NoncurrentVersionExpiration": {
            "NoncurrentDays": 3650
        },
        "AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload": {
            "DaysAfterInitiation": 7
        }
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over the bucket names and [put-bucket-lifecycle-configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-lifecycle-configuration.html) on each one.  For example:

```
for bucket in $(aws s3api list-buckets --query "Buckets[].Name" --output text); do

    aws s3api put-bucket-lifecycle-configuration --bucket ${bucket} --lifecycle-configuration file://lifecycle.json

done
```

Comment: How can I run this command? Would I put this in a bash file and run the bash file?

I'm on windows 10 machine running cmder for linux commands.